# Orchard encoding issues

Tags: orchardcms

I have some encoding issues in Orchard CMS. When i use these characters: "ěščřžýááí" output is this: `&#237`;.

This problem is not everywhere ! In admin new content type menu it is OK, but in title, when creating new content type it is wrong.

In front-end is the same problem with validation messages only.

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Localization](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Using-the-localization-helpers/) is designed to solve this issue, use it this way:

```
@T("ěščřžýááí")
```

I do it regularly and I never had this problem.